# Background Notifications + Windows 8

Tags: c#, windows, background

I have a simple Windows 8 Application which shows Notifications when the timer reaches 0.
Now I want those Notifications to only be shown when there APP is on Background.

How can I check that ?

```
protected void Back_Tick(object sender, object e)
        {
            if (stageSequence.Current.RemainningTime == TimeSpan.Zero)
            {
                if(stageSequence.MoveNext() == true)
                {
                    var typeOfNotification = TypeOfNotification.EndOfStage;
                    // Check If it is on background
                    ToastAlarmNotification(lblStage.Text, typeOfNotification);
                    lblStage.Text = stageSequence.Current.Name;
                    lblTime.Text = stageSequence.Current.RemainningTime.ToString();
                    mediaElementEndOfStage.Play();
                }
                else
                {
                    var typeOfNotification = TypeOfNotification.EndOfStage;
                    dispatcherTimer.Stop();
                    // Check If it is on background
                    ToastAlarmNotification(lblStage.Text, typeOfNotification);
                    typeOfNotification = TypeOfNotification.EndOfList;
                    ToastAlarmNotification(lblStage.Text, typeOfNotification);
                    mediaElementFinal.Play();
                    return;
                }
            }

            stageSequence.Current.RemainningTime = stageSequence.Current.RemainningTime.Subtract(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
            lblTime.Text = stageSequence.Current.RemainningTime.ToString();
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could register for the [CoreWindow.VisibilityChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.corewindow.visibilitychanged.aspx) event in your UI thread and store `VisibilityChangedEventArgs.Visible` value.